# What does $%,.2f represent?

Tags: java, printf

I am currently reading the Deitel's book on Java, and came across this code in one of their programs:

```
public String toString()
{
  return String.format( "%s: %s\n%s: $%,.2f; %s: %.2f", 
     "commission employee", super.toString(), 
     "gross sales", getGrossSales(), 
     "commission rate", getCommissionRate() );
}
```

As the title says, what does the "$%," in front of the ".2f" represent? I already know what a .2f means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` character means nothing special here.  It's just a literal `$` to show up in the string.  The `%` character takes it's usual meaning here -- to substitute with a value (here, with 2 decimal places).

Note that it's possible for the `$` character to have meaning after the `%` character.  Please see the "Argument Index" section of the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadocs for details.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I always thought that you couldn't put other signs or words next to conversion characters without space

Answer (score 6):

The $ is literally the dollar sign while the % is the beginning of the argument %,.2f (a float with 2 decimals and a comma)

Answer (score 4):

`%,.2f`  - format float with 2 decimal places with comma.